# How to place each value of an array on each cell of Excel?

Tags: javascript, html

When pushing a button of "Make a CSV file!" , I can download a csv file with values below.

Here is my question: would you give me any ideas to have each value of <td> tags on each cell when I open the csv file with Excel?

Currently, my csv has each <tr> values in one cell. (e.g. A1-cell has 'Mansfield Park', 'Jane Austine', ''. A2-cell has 'Great Expectations', 'Charles Dickens', '')
So, could you tell me to have each value in each cell?
(e.g. A1 has 'Mansfield Park', B1 has 'Jane Austine', C1 has '')

I think that I need to rewrite this JS code

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Make Your Words</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head">
      <h1>Be Free to Create your Vocabulary!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="transtable">
      <table class="table" id="ENJP" border="1">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Author</th>
            <th scope="col">NOTE</th>
          </tr>
          <!-- Data is fetched by MongoDB -->
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="opt_1">
      <input type="button" value="Show Data"/>
      <input type="button" value="Add a Row" onclick="AddRow()"/>
      <input id="download" type="button" class="btn" value="Make a CSV File!" onclick="MakeCSV()"/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="opt_2">
      <h4>Name Your File!</h4>
      <input id="FileName" type="text" placeholder="Input a File Name"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src=script.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
let table = document.getElementById("ENJP");
const AddRow = () => {
    //テーブルに新行追加
    let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
    //追加行の内容を決定（セルを１つずつ作る）
    let cel_EN = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    let cel_JP = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    let cel_NOTE = newRow.insertCell(-1);
    let rowContentEN = '<input type="text" name="Title"/>';
    let rowContentJP = '<input type="text" name="Author"/>';
    let rowContentNOTE = '<input type="text" name="NOTE"/>';
    cel_EN.innerHTML = rowContentEN;
    cel_JP.innerHTML = rowContentJP;
    cel_NOTE.innerHTML = rowContentNOTE;
}

const MakeCSV = () => {
// 抽出したデータを格納する配列変数
    let data = [];
 // id(ENJP)でhtmlからtableの要素を取得し、trタグのListを取得
    let table = document.getElementById('ENJP');
    let tbl_tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
 //テーブルの1行(trタグ)毎に処理
    tbl_tr.forEach(function(tr){
     //tdタグを取得・テーブルのヘッダー部分は飛ばす
        let cells = tr.querySelectorAll('td');
        if (cells.length!=0){
         // テーブルの1行(trタグ)のデータを格納する配列
            let d =[];
         //セル(tdタグ)毎に処理
            cells.forEach(function(td){
             //セルがinputタグだった場合
                if(td.innerHTML.indexOf('input') != -1) {
                 d.push(td.value);
                 
                }
             //セルがtextだった場合
                else if(td.textContent!=""){
                  d.push(td.textContent);
                }
             //セルが空白だった場合
                else{
                    d.push("");
                }
            });
         data.push(d);
        }
    });
 //ここで配列への格納終わり。

 //CSV Creation
    let bom = new Uint8Array([0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF]);
//Here is what I think is necessary to revise.
    let csvData = data.map((data) => data.join('\t')).join('\r\n');
    let blob = new Blob([bom,csvData], {'type' : 'text/csv'});
//ダウンロード時の処理
    let downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.download = document.getElementById("FileName").value + '.csv';
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', downloadLink.download, downloadLink.href].join(':');
    downloadLink.click();
    console.log(data);
return window.alert("You get it")
}

const mongoGet = async () =>{
    try {
        console.log("show");
        // Serverにリクエスト投げる。axios.get()でAPIを叩く処理
        let allbks = await axios.get("/book");
        console.log(allbks);
        let { data } = allbks;
        //出力
        allbks = data.map((book) => {
            const { id,title,author,other } = book;
            console.log(id,title,author,other);
            let newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
            let cel_EN = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            let cel_JP = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            let cel_NOTE = newRow.insertCell(-1);
            let rowContentEN = `${title}`;
            let rowContentJP = `${author}`;
            let rowContentNOTE = `<input type="text" name="NOTE"/>`;
            console.log(title)
            cel_EN.innerHTML = rowContentEN;
            cel_JP.innerHTML = rowContentJP;
            cel_NOTE.innerHTML = rowContentNOTE;
            return console.log("did it!");
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
}
mongoGet();
```

My trouble will be resolved if I revise the JS code which processes values.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the JS code, you are producing a file in tab-separated format, not comma-separated format.
Try to give it an extension ".tsv" instead of ".csv". Excel will parse it differently.

Comment: dami-san, thank you so much for your idea.  I was very grateful to it as one of my options for future coding. Actually, before I reached your support, I had been able to solve my issue by changing what I thought was something wrong to this code. ``` let csvData = data.map((data) => String(data).replace('\t',',')).join('\r\n')```   Anyway, I would like to thank you for your kindest help.